# Why was this old question closed when it was asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589681/c-sharp-nested-functions-with-recursion) over two years ago, when I was a novice to C#. It demonstrated my lack of understanding of the language, but my question was in no way unclear. I wanted to know how to do classic functional recursion in C#.

None of the people who voted to close gave specific feedback via comments on what was unclear, and I received a good answer to the question that resolved the gap in my knowledge. It was brought to my attention again this morning, and now that I have more experience with the site I realized I fail to see any of the site guidelines I violated in asking the question.

What were some of the reasons it was closed?

**EDIT: I've edited the question - would appreciate feedback now as well.**

Comment: Just an interesting observation - it was closed shortly after it was asked and only brought to your attention recently by someone else who had just stumbled upon it.

Comment: It could have been closed as too broad if you prefer?

Comment: @BoltClock That's a fair point. I'd forgotten about it until that comment, but now that I have a better understanding of the site I realized I didn't know why it was closed.

Comment: @Sayse: Are you implying it's not nearly as simple as either the pseudo-code in the question, or the solution in the answer, suggests?

Comment: @Sayse In what way? Classical recursion really only manifests itself in one or two ways in any given language. For a novice attempting to understand a language, how would that question have better been asked?

Comment: Hard to imagine what more feedback you want.  If you mumble something under your breath and your friend cannot understand what you say then he says "What?"   What else do you expect him to say?

Comment: @BoltClock - I was referring to the "There are either too many possible answers, .." portion of the close reason, judging the question purely on its own merits.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure I follow. The question received an answer from someone who understood the intentions of the question.

Comment: One person is not enough, SO is not a personal help desk.  Your question needs to be understandable to anybody that has the same problem.  So they can find that answer.

Comment: The person who answered didn't understand your question, though. They understood the comment asking for clarification and guessed what an answer might look like based on that. The question really is not very clear.

Comment: @BilltheLizard So then that lends itself to another question - for a complete novice browsing the site (and trust me, I see it all the time in JavaScript) questions are unclear because fundamentals haven't been solidified. It's not their fault, there's just a knowledge gap. Why shouldn't answers concerning fundamentals (or even unknown fundamentals) be good candidates for the site? For someone who didn't understand how to do recursion in C#, did you really expect them to know the term "recursive delegate"?

Comment: Questions about fundamentals are perfectly on-topic. This one was closed because it was unclear what you were asking, not because it was about fundamentals.

Comment: @HansPassant This is somewhat unrelated to the original question, but I'd dispute the notion that SO doesn't function as a "personal help desk". Questions are often specific to the point that there's almost no possibility of general applicability, but people help the users out anyway. There's chat, which gives a place for personal discussion, and there have been many users who have taken the time to walk me through problems there.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think new users should come to the website with the *expectation* of their problem being solved, but I also think one of the great things about SO is that the site cares as much about the individual as a community pool of knowledge.

Comment: As for how it was closed, that was due to review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3584147 . One person left a (now deleted) comment stating "What is this function of which you speak? If you want a recursive method, then just use that.", voted to close, and the rest of the reviewers went along with that. If I remember correctly, close vote review audits had not been implemented at that time, so a lot of people clicked "Close" as quickly as they could in that review queue without reading anything that came in. Not necessarily saying that happened here, but it was common at the time.

Answer (score 7):

The question, if you read it literally, is:

> Any ideas?

It may be hard to understand what exactly you wanted to ask. To make the question more clear, you should be more specific. For example:

> I cannot possibly write my code this way, because ... (write why)
>
> So, how should I organize my code?

Or

> I want to write my code this way. However, I don't understand what I should put in line 2? I tried, `frobnicate(fred)` but it frobnicates the wrong `fred`. How to fix this?

In other words, you should be more specific.

Comment: So pardon me if I misunderstood, but the "any ideas" is the offending line? The pseudocode was intended to explain the desired behavior, but there's no verbal description of that including in the question, other than the "with the parameters of a parent function accessible to the nested child" before it.

Comment: @Harangue: No, the abundant vagueness is.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not trying to be defensive of this question (it was two years ago!), I'm just genuinely curious about the issues with it. This answer above was helpful, but your comment is not adding anything to the discussion. Are there any specifics you'd like to point out, or answer the actual question I posed?

Comment: I think "any ideas?" is part of the problem. It's very broad and open-ended, and if you take that away, what is the question you're trying to ask?

Comment: You should explain exactly where you are stuck. Imagine an infinitely wise programmer, who can understand and write code of any complexity. He will never understand what your problem is, if you don't state it explicitly. He may start guessing like "probably OP doesn't know about feature X of his language" or "obviously his code is missing a semicolon - that is the answer!" or "the code works OK if you do a trivial fix; probably OP is asking about additional ideas on how to make the code better". To prevent people guessing in random directions, just ask a specific question.

Comment: Hey, I've made some improvements. Will you look at if it meets the guidelines now?

Comment: Essentially "Any ideas" (or similar text as question) is symptom, not the problem - it usually shows that OP did not thought about problem enough to have good question. It likely drops post from "could be good" down to "likely too broad" for person looking at the post - and unless one have too much free time to dig through the question to verify it may lead to quick downvote/close (definitely not an ideal practice...but with amount of questions SO has..)